# Can "anachronism" refer to things that have not been done in the proper order?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I've looked in a few online dictionaries, and I don't see any definitions of "anachronism" that seem to encompass this situation. However, I feel like, etymologically, this term could be used in the following way:

> Since some construction was begun before the designs were truly complete, I have added four days to our estimate to account for the inefficiencies caused by these various anachronisms.

It seems like it *should* be able to be used this way, but I'm not aware of any precedent. If this cannot be a usage of "anachronism," can you suggest a word that could be used in this context? I'm mainly looking for a noun that refers to actions that occurred in an order other than the proper/established order.

Comment: Just because a meaning is etymologically appropriate for a word, doesn't mean you can actually use the word for that meaning and be understood.

Comment: I think you're trying to squeeze too much meaning into a single word. You added those days to account for *inefficiencies caused by the fact of having already done some things in a non-optimal sequence.*

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I agree. That's why I thought I should ask here to see if people would understand. I don't plan on using it in formal writing after reading your and FumbleFingers's comments.
FumbleFingers, I don't think my example conveyed what I meant. I really am trying to refer to just the "things done in a non-optimal sequence." I am updating the example to better show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OED carries only two senses of the word *anachronism* (see below), which involve the ascribing of something to a wrong time-period, such as when the clock strikes in Shakespeare's *Julius Caesar*. They didn't have striking clocks in ancient Rome, whilst they had them in Shakespeare's day.

I feel sure that the instance you quote is a malapropism. I would have said *...inefficiencies caused by these premature starts*.

> 1.An error in computing time, or fixing dates; the erroneous reference of an event, circumstance, or custom to a wrong date. Said
>   etymologically (like prochronism) of a date which is too early, but
>   also used of too late a date, which has been distinguished as
>   parachronism.
>
> 2. Anything done or existing out of date; hence, anything which was proper to a former age, but is, or, if it existed, would be, out of
>      harmony with the present; also called a practical anachronism. Also
>      transf. of persons.

Answer (score 0):

"out-of-sequence events" is as concise a substitute as I can come up with.

If you want to be crude and sarcastic, you could say "because we did it bass-ackwards"  (which is, if you didn't know, a euphemism for "ass-backwards"). But this refers to the  out-of-sequence-ness of the whole series of events, not to any one event.